Creating wasm in rust with duckdb as dependency
I’m developing a Rust library with DuckDB as a key dependency. The library successfully cross-compiles for various platforms like Windows, macOS, and Android. However, I’m encountering errors while trying to build it for WebAssembly (WASM).
Could you please help me resolve these issues or share any insights on building DuckDB with Rust for WASM?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Would you be able to provide more information on the particular errors you are encountering?
